# Fade in different lines of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, delay, fadein

I am trying to fade in three separate lines of text, each one delayed slightly later than the last. I have discovered how to fade a single line, and how to delay a single line, but whatever I try cannot combine the two.  All the JS research is for .fadeIn('slow') for button selectors and whatever tried doesn't work with the code below . Any advice appreciated.

```
function showText(id,delay){
  var elem=document.getElementById(id);
  setTimeout(function(){elem.style.visibility='visible';},delay*1000)
}

window.onload = function(){
  showText('delayedText1',1);
  showText('delayedText2',2);
  showText('delayedText3',3);
  showText('delayedText4',4);
}

<h1 id="delayedText1" style="visibility:hidden">First line fades in</h1>
<h1 id="delayedText2" style="visibility:hidden">slightly later this fades in</h1>
<h1 id="delayedText3" style="visibility:hidden">and last this line fades in</h1>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k4h94Lob/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of CSS transitions for this.

Transitions need a numeric value to function, so you can use the `opacity` style, rather than `visibility`:

```js
function showText(id, delay) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    setTimeout(function () {
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
    }, delay * 1000)
}
window.onload = function () {
    showText('delayedText1', 1);
    showText('delayedText2', 2);
    showText('delayedText3', 3);
    showText('delayedText4', 4);
}
```

```css
h1{
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="delayedText1" style="">First line fades in</h1>
<h1 id="delayedText2" style="">slightly later this fades in</h1>
<h1 id="delayedText3" style="">and last this line fades in</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think you'll be doing more with animation in your project I highly recommend using [Animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css). Then how about not using JavaScript at all for the delay, and keep it real simple with some CSS?

```
<h1 id="delayedText1" class="animated fadeIn delay-1">First line fades in</h1>
<h1 id="delayedText2" class="animated fadeIn delay-2">slightly later this fades in</h1>
<h1 id="delayedText3" class="animated fadeIn delay-3">and last this line fades in</h1>
```

For example:

```
.delay-1 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 300ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: none;
    animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.delay-2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 600ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: none;
    animation-delay: 600ms;
}
.delay-3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 900ms;
    -moz-animation-delay: none;
    animation-delay: 900ms;
}
```

**[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/rn4rx46y/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var numOfLines = 3;
     var delay = 1000;
     var fadeTime = 1000;
     for (i = 0; i < numOfLines + 1; i++) { 
        $('#delayedText' + i).delay(delay * i).fadeIn(fadeTime);
     }
  });
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h8nzwj7L/4/) and Be sure to change

```
visibility:hidden with display:none;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5fd5zy9r/3)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('h1').each(function (line) {
        $(this).delay((line++) * 1000).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** Note that this will work for any number of lines. You can change fade in speed and delay time.